# Getting fully qualified class name from aliased class in Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I setup aliases in my Laravel 8 application's **config/app.php**. I can use them in Blade to access the class being aliased as expected. But using the `class` constant does not give me the fully qualified class name.

```php
@can('viewAny', User::class)
```

What I tried:

```php
@dump(User::class) // 'User'
@dump(\App\Models\User::class) // 'App\Models\User'
@dump((new User)::class) // 'App\Models\User' (PHP 8)
@dump(SomeMadeUpClass::class) // 'SomeMadeUpClass'
```

Should I be able to get the fully qualified class name from an aliased class? Or is there an alternative syntax that I can use with `@can` without specifying the model's namespace and class (`@can('viewAny', \App\Models\User)`)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since all the aliases added to `config/app.php` is loaded via `AliasLoader` you can get actual class name from there.

Try this Code

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

$aliasLoaderInstance = AliasLoader::getInstance()->getAliases();

dump($aliasLoaderInstance);

//replace URL with the aliases you need
dump(Arr::get($aliasLoaderInstance,'URL',null));
//will print     Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL
```